# do SSH keys have to be unique to the service they are used for?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-keys

I just created a virtual server (or, in the language of Digital Ocean host, a 'droplet') for the first time. Digital Ocean has an instruction page about SSH keys https://www.digitalocean.com/ssh_keys  tells us to check if SSH keys exist, and then it gives instructions for generating new SSH keys and then to add them. In my case, using the command that the instructions gave, I discovered that I already have SSH keys (which I'm guessing I generated when I signed up for github or heroku)

Questions

1) Should I reuse the SSH keys I already have or generate new keys (i.e. do they have to be unique to the service I use them for)?

2) The instructions (copied below) talk about adding SSH keys to digital ocean and then creating a server. In my case, I created the server before adding SSH keys. Will this create any kind of problem I should be aware of?  Should I destroy the server (which hasn't anything installed on it yet) and create a new one adding the SSH keys at the appropriate time?

Instructions

```
You can add SSH keys to DigitalOcean which can then be selected during the droplet create process to add the selected SSH keys under the root user.

When using SSH keys a root password will no longer be set as SSH keys will be used as the preferred method of access.

We do not manage the server after creation, so editing, adding, or removing SSH keys from the SSH interface will not affect any of the stored keys on droplets that you have created.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SSH keys do not have to be unique to a particular service. As a matter of good general practice they *should be unique to a purpose*.

For example you as a person may have several SSH keys:
 - A key for your personal systems
 - A key for your work systems
 - A key you use with github/rsync.net/etc.

At work you may also have keys dedicated to specific programs (one used by Puppet, one used by backup software, etc.)

You should consider your security and confidentiality needs, then determine if you should create a new key, or use an existing key.

---

The instructions you pasted seem to indicate that when you create a "droplet" Digital Ocean adds specified keys to root's `authorized_keys` file.  After that they do not manage the `authorized_keys` file further, so if you've already created a server *without* specifying keys (or you want to add/change/delete keys later) you will need to manually edit root's `authorized_keys` file to make those changes.
You do not need to destroy/re-create the server for this.

Comment: ok, thanks, I'm going to reuse the ssh keys that I already have and which I currently only use for limited purpose (github/heroku) as that seems easiest. I just wanted to know if it was necessarily wrong to do so

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about DigitalOcean.

You can use the same ssh key for everything, but in some circumstances it may be better not to.  If you are forwarding your key using an SSH agent, then there's a risk that someone with root privileges on the machine you forward to may be able to use your key, for as long as you are still connected.  Where else they could connect to using that key depends on where else you used the same key.  Many would consider such concerns paranoid, but equally there are circumstances which require a great deal of care (even paranoia).  You know what's at stake more than I do.

Be aware that you can sometimes get unexpected results if you put the same key into an `.ssh/authorized_keys` file twice.  Avoid that.